# Understanding error in haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes, http-conduit

I (New to Haskell) am trying to perform unpack operation on ByteString that I receive from webpage. Basically I want to search few words from webpage so I am trying to tokenize stream, then search word from words.

```
Prelude Network.HTTP.Conduit LB> LB.unpack (simpleHttp WebLink)
```

But I am getting below error

```
<interactive>:75:12: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘LB.ByteString’
              with actual type ‘m0 LB.ByteString’
• In the first argument of ‘LB.unpack’, namely...
```

From hackage I can see that its signature is

```
unpack :: ByteString -> [Word8] Source
O(n) Converts a ByteString to a '[Word8]'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`simpleHttp "http://example.com"` is of type `m ByteString`, for some monad `m`, so for example of type `IO ByteString`. Using `do` notation you can get at the result.

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

main :: IO ()
main = do
  res <- simpleHttp "http://example.com"
  let string = LB.unpack res
  putStr string
```

Or in ghci,

```
ghci> res <- simpleHttp "http://example.com"
ghci> LB.unpack res
```

Answer (score 2):

`simpleHttp WebLink` appears to be a monadic action that *returns* a value, it's not a ByteString itself.  You must run the procedure, obtaining the value, then (assuming it is a bytestring) you can unpack it.

Note that the [`simpleHttp`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.3.3/docs/Network-HTTP.html#v:simpleHTTP) procedure I know of does not return a bytestring.  You'll want to pattern match on the return value to inspect the `Either` type, if it is a response message instead of a failure then you can further pattern match on the response.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply and explanation of problem. Can you please suggest some link or some example to do what you suggested?